# function called from elsewhere behaves differently

Tags: c#, mvvm, barcode-scanner

I have a function (Called `OpenExcel()`)that opens an excel document and reads its values.

For the function to know what excel document to open, a string value must be provided. But in MVVM application with a barcode reader, the function will execute before the property has its value assigned. (I have tried with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in the Binding with no luck.)

I ended up using the PreviewTextInput Event of the TextBox, to manually assign to the property (which works).

My issue is that when I call the function from code-behind, the List in the View does not update with the values. (I have stepped through the function and checked that there are values there). However, when I call the function through Prism's ICommand, the list displays all the values.

All Relevant Code:

XAML:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Serial,Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="serial_txt" PreviewKeyDown="serial_txt_PreviewKeyDown" PreviewTextInput="serial_txt_PreviewTextInput" />
<Button Command="{Binding GetFollower}"/>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Parts}"/>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public ListViewModel view;

public LCMList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    view = new ListViewModel();
}

private void serial_txt_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Enter) //scanned string is always followed by Enter input. 
    {
        view.OpenExcel(sender); //Fails if called from here              
    }
} 

private void serial_txt_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    view.Serial += e.Text;
}
```

ListViewModel:

```
public ICommand GetFollower
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(OpenExcel); } //Succeeds if called from here
}

private string serial;
public string Serial
{
    get { return serial; }
    set 
    { 
        serial = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("Serial");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Part> parts;
public ObservableCollection<Part> Parts
{
    get { return parts; }
    set 
    { 
        parts = value; 
        SetProperty(ref parts, value); 
        OnPropertyChanged("Parts");
    }
}

public void OpenExcel(object obj)
{
    /* Find Excel document and read the applicable fields and put into partslist. 
       Needs Serial property as reference */
    Parts = partslist;
}
```

The Parts property gets its values written to, but the list in View stays empty.

In Conclusion:
function updates the properties properly when called through prism and DelegateCommand, but not when called from CodeBehind.

Comment: Calling `parts = value;` could cause `SetProperty(ref parts, value);` to work unexpected. - Try to use `.Clear()` and `.AddRange()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rand. I tried to comment out the `SetProperty(ref parts, value);` but the issue persist the same way it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
   public LCMList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        view = DataCotnex;
    }

   private void serial_txt_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter) //scanned string is always followed by Enter input. 
        {
            view.OpenExcel(sender); //Fails if called from here              
        }
    }
```

you can try that

```
   private void serial_txt_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter) //scanned string is always followed by Enter input. 
        {
            if (!(DataContext is ListViewModel vm)) return;
                vm.OpenExcel(sender);             
        }
    }
```

also don't forget to add datacontext in XAML

```
    <Window.DataContext>
         <local:ListViewModel  />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alp! This worked, I don't know why, but this solved the issue.

Comment: Let me tell you why. I'm not sure but probably that's why: `view = new ListViewModel();`. You are saying that my view is new ListViewModel and not your context. In my way i say my datacontext as ListViewModel :) Happy to hear its worked. Good day.